# Opening a web browser and controlling it as a Virtual User

Tags: java, javascript

I am trying to open a browser and then simulate a user in Java. Previously I would have accomplished this with simple Applescript, with something like this

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
open location "http://google.co.uk"
delay 1
do JavaScript "
    document.getElementById('gbqfq').value ='software is hard';
" in document 1
end tell
```

So it opens Safari, then types into Google's query box.

In Java, so far I have

```
import javax.script.*;
public class VirtualUser {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Applications/Safari.app");   
Thread.sleep(1000);

ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval("print('Hello World')");
}
}
```

Which opens Safari (Google homepage), and prints Hello World in the IDE (verification that JS is working within Java?)

In the Java example, how can I then further enter text into Google's search bar? And is utilising JavaScript within Java the best/only solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some luck with [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) in the past. It automates a browser and you can run commands exactly like you are describing. Definitely go check it out.

Comment: Certainly looks like the perfect solution.